# Is self defined property in CSS selector a good choice?

Tags: css

```
<button bg="blue">blue</button>
<button bg="red">red</button>

[bg="blue"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
[bg="red"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Integ/pen/YPRpWE

No class, no ID, just properties.

Comment: You are about to use non-standard attribute, HTML validator will complain for this however browsers will work fine with this.

Comment: No. It's messy and non-standard. What would you have to gain by doing this, that you couldn't achieve with classes already?

Comment: "No class, no ID" But you have an attribute. A non-standard one at that. So it's not "just properties." If you really wanted to define CSS properties in HTML, why don't you use inline styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class is more efficient.

```
.bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}


<div class="bg-blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is called attribute equal selector. Yes, you can use it on your own depending the requirement. Of course, if you don't have set class or id then you can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

### Suggestion:

Use data-* attributes instead of attributes for your custom attributes(It is valid in html5). Example:

```
<button data-bg="blue">blue</button>
```